# How To Deploy a Node.js and MongoDB Application on Linux server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, deployment, keystonejs

I am developing an app and I want to deploy it on a linux server. I already have copy my local files to the server . I have read this article but not so clear to me https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/4687.

## things i have already done

Remote server has appropriate versions of Node.js & npm installed (ideally the same as what you have been testing with in development)

Check out (or copy) the latest version of your application source to the remote server.

Run npm install (or npm install --production if this will be a production environment) in the top-level of your application source directory.

but when i run npm start on the server it gives me error which is

Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

## my settings

```
keystone.init({
    'name': 'Test',
    'brand': 'Test',
    'sass': 'public',
    'static': 'public',
    'favicon': 'public/favicon.ico',
    'auto update': true,
    'views': 'templates/views',
    'view engine': '.html',
    'custom engine': cons.nunjucks,
    'mongo': 'mongodb://localhost/test',
    'auto update': true,
    'emails': 'templates/email',
    'session': true,
    'auth': true,
    'user model': 'User',
});
```

Do i need to configure more settings on mongo on the server?

Comment: Check that mongo db server was started or not by finding process, you can get it by commnd: `service mongod status`.

Comment: Unit mongod.service could not be found.

Comment: @MonarthSarvaiya , are you still there?

Comment: Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

Comment: After i done all of that Sir , would i be suing the ip address on the server ? or this settings will remain   'mongo': 'mongodb://localhost/test', ?

Comment: cause i am deploying it on a linux server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197242/discussion-between-monarth-sarvaiya-and-mr-rajiv-kumar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mongoose connection "error" event fired with: { MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect

The above error means that your mongodb service was not started.

To enable & start the mongodb service you can run following command:

**1. Enable mongodb service**

```
sudo systemctl enable mongod.service
```

**2. Start mongodb service**

```
sudo service mongod start
```

**3. Start your nodejs app**

```
npm start
```

Comment: hey sir are you there?